# How to check if a Tensorflow Session is still open (without catching an exception)?

Tags: tensorflow

Is there a way in Tensorflow to find if a given `tf.Session()` is still open? The only way I have found so far is to try to use it, and catch the exception when it is not open.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check if session._closed is True

```
sess = tf.Session()
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init_op)
print(sess._closed)
sess.close()
print(sess._closed)
```

Output

```
False
True
```

Comment: From your code snippet, if I remove the second line
`init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()`

I get output

`False
False`

instead. Any idea why?

Comment: If you remove those you are not opening the session. Check sess._opened

Comment: Is there a way to view all open sessions?